Spotfire's "~=" not matching wildcard characters
Using Spotfire Alanyst 14.0.3
I'm in the Data Canvas adding a filter via the "Add transformation" feature.
When I use the filter expression ...
[customdata_name]~='Binary Pump : 1 : RunStart_Pressure_Actual'
... I get hundreds of rows (Binary Pump : * : RunStart_Pressure_Actual is the actual full string in the column customdata_name)
However, when I use...
[customdata_name]~='Binary Pump : * : RunStart_Pressure_Actual' (replacing only the character "1" with "*")
...I get no rows.
Why is the wildcard character not being recognized?
P.s. For reasons unknown to me LIKE is not available as a function to replace ~=.
